# "missing operator" error message while using the "set /a" command

Tags: parameters, batch-file, set

Ok so ive been finishing off my batch program called "stringparsing.bat" and the last error im having trouble with is one that says "missing operator" when i use the following snippet:

```
set /p linecount= 
cls
set foo=0
set linenumber=0

:lineset
set /a linenumber=%linenumber% +1
set /p line1= %linenumber% 
echo %line1% >> %name%.txt
set /a foo=%foo%+1
set /a line number=%linenumber%+1
IF %foo%==%linecount% goto MAIN123
goto lineset
```

More specificly, ive narrowed it down to :

```
set /a linenumber=%linenumber% +1
    set /p line1= %linenumber%
```

Im pretty sure im mis-using the **set /p** command... what i am trying to do, is make a prompt that asks the user to input how many lines of text that they are going to insert into a text file. Then make a loop that asks the user to type some text which is then sent to the  text file. But i wanted to to put the line number before the prompt so that it would look like this:

[image]

So when the batch file asks for the first line, it says 1: , and when it asks for the second line, its says 2: , and so on. after each line prompt, i get the "missing operator" error message... Btw i need to use this scirpt to get it to work:

set /p line1= %linenumber%+1

But in order to use this command with the **+1** at the end, do i have to add the **/a** parameter as well as the **/p** parameter?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple **echo on** could help here :-)

In your line **set /a line number=%linenumber%+1** is a space linenumber, that is a problem.

Another thing, it is not neccessary to use

```
set /a linenumber=%linenumber% +1
```

It is better to use

```
set /a linenumber=linenumber+1
or
set /a linenumber+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Set /A cannot handle fractions aka numbers with decimal points. Set /? says:

> Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for
> hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.